# PHP If Not In CSV but In Database

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have a script where i am updating posts from a CSV file. I have the insert and update methods however I can not work out the delete methods.

Here is the function:

```
$registration = $csv_data["REGISTRATION"];

function delete_cars_in_db($registration) {
    $car_query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='registration'";

    $delete_car = $wpdb->get_results($car_query);

    foreach($delete_car as $dcar) {
        if($dcar->meta_value != $registration) {
            echo "Delete Car" . $dcar->meta_value;
            wp_delete_post($dcar->post_id);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that the if statement does not work.

I would think that the logic here would be:
if it is not in the CSV but in the database then delete the post.

This is for a wordpress plugin.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tested the if-statement? If yes, what is the result. If no, why not?

Comment: If it were me, I would be echoing out `$registration` and `$dcar->meta_value` to see if they appear to be the same or different on each iteration.

Comment: Building on above comment, maybe use `var_dump()` to output the vars - as there might be rogue spaces, which you can `trim()` off if needed.

Comment: @Bernhard @dmikester1 I have done exactly that. There are 5 rows in the CSV and what happens is on the iteration when they are both the same it says no car to delete, however when they are different for the other 4 rows it says delete car, so the if does not work. I am thinking that I put the registrations into an array and then use `if(!in_array) { then delete }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your desired logic of:

*"Delete car post from DB if the registration does not have a match in the CSV"*

...then this might get you on the right track:

```
function delete_cars_in_db() {

    // Get list of cars in DB
    $car_query = "SELECT id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='registration'";
    $cars_in_db = $wpdb->get_results($car_query);

    // Get list of cars from CSV
    $cars_in_csv = array();
    $file = fopen("/path/to/yourfile.csv","r");

    // Loop CSV
    while(!feof($file)){

        $csv_data = fgetcsv($file);

        // Build array of registrations
        $cars_in_csv[] = $csv_data['x']; // Enter column number of `registration` column from your CSV

    }

    fclose($file);


    // Check if the cars from DB exist in CSV - delete if there is no match
    foreach($cars_in_db as $car){

        if(!in_array($car->meta_value, $cars_in_csv)){
            echo "Delete Car" . $car->meta_value;
            wp_delete_post($car->post_id);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @lumonald! Thank you so much for this! You have resolved my problem, this works brilliantly!!

Comment: @StevenHardy Glad it helped.